# Twitter API OAuth cannot find 'authorization_url'

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, python-requests

I'm writing a code that uses Twitter API to get users' statuses, number of followers etc. I need to write a script that opens browser and asks users to sign in and let me get the authentication from them.

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from urlparse import parse_qs

client_key = "keykeykeykey"
client_secret = "keykeykeykeykey"
request_token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
fetch_response = oauth.fetch_request_token(request_token_url)
#print(fetch_response)
resource_owner_key = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
resource_owner_secret = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')
oauth = OAuth1(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
r = requests.post(url=request_token_url, auth=oauth)
#print(r.content)
credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
resource_owner_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
resource_owner_secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]
base_authorization_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
authorization_url = oauth.authorization_url(base_authorization_url)
print 'Please go here and authorize,', authorization_url
redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here: ')
oauth_response = oauth.parse_authorization_response(redirect_response)
#print(oauth_response)
verifier = oauth_response.get('oauth_verifier')
authorize_url = base_authorization_url + '?oauth_token='
authorize_url = authorize_url + resource_owner_key
print 'Please go here and authorize,', authorize_url
verifier = raw_input('Please input the verifier')
```

I have found this kind of example from internet but it gives an error like :

```
AttributeError: 'OAuth1' object has no attribute 'authorization_url'
```

I have checked the session info and actually there is authorization_url here:
https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_session.py

Comment: authentication_url is not the same as authorization_url?

Comment: Sorry I misspelled and edited it :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you use the oauth variable as an OauthSession object and a Oauth1 object.

```
oauth = OAuth1Session(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
oauth = OAuth1(client_key, client_secret=client_secret)
```

It should work if you use it as a session object